# Run SQL after submit button

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to delete certain table / row using WP SQL when the submit button is clicked but didn't seem to get it right. What went wrong? Thanks!

```html
function delete_commands()
{
  include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
  global $wpdb;
  ?>

  <form method="POST">
   <input class="btn" style="float:none;" type="submit"  name="delete" value="Delete all orders"  />
 </form>

  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix;

        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM {$table_name}_erp_ac_transactions WHERE ID = 12" ) );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single `$` before `wpdb->query`, fix your query like:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM {$table_name}_erp_ac_transactions WHERE ID = %d", 12) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried but still not removing the entry in the db. Any idea what went wrong?
If I run the SQL directly in the phpMyAdmin with the SQL it works.

Comment: can you send me table full name display in phpmyadmin?

Comment: wp_12baa7b8cf_erp_ac_transactions

Comment: $wpdb->prefix will return prefix with  _  and you added  _ before table name maybe it will look like  " wp__erp_ac_transactions " and two-time _ will be added

Comment: use {$table_name}erp_ac_transactions  in query

Comment: so your query look like this  ==>  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM {$table_name}erp_ac_transactions WHERE ID = 12 ");

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems to be related to the POST. Cannot figure out what's wrong.